# Dynamically highlight lightning:Datatable Row

Tags: lightning-datatable

I'm using a lightning:datatable to display some data coming from a third party web service. I have a scenario to dynamically highlight a row based on a specific condition. How can I do that? What specific datatable action I shall use?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no way to do so using the standard component. You will need to build something custom here and dynamically change the styling of the row based on the condition.